# Review of this linked list program

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

This is a program on the linked list which prints the given input. But is it possible to do it Without using the `if(start==NULL) ...else ..` statement?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
}* start = NULL;

void main()
{
    struct node* tmp;
    struct node *ptr, *tmp1;

    int n = 0;
    int choice = 2;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter a number less than 3 to continue");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        if (choice >= 3)
            break;

        printf("Enter the input");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        // n=n+10;
        if (start == NULL)
        {
            tmp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            start = tmp;
            start->data = n;
            ptr = start;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            ptr->next = tmp;
            tmp->data = n;
            ptr = tmp;
        }
    }
    tmp->next = NULL;


    printf("\nThe output of the linked list is\n");
    n = 0;
    ptr = start;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("\n  1 ptr =           %d", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want the code to do? What does it do instead?

Comment: @Broman I just want to insert a few values in the nodes and just print them.Its working.But my doubt is it possible without using this if (start==NULL) ...else .. statement

Comment: It's in fact necessary to distinguish the case where `start` is `NULL` from the opposite (where it is not `NULL`). However, there is a lot of code duplication in the then- and else-branch. This is something which could be eliminated.

Comment: @Scheff can you please give me the code after duplication.I will be greatful to you

Comment: With `if (ptr == NULL) { start = ptr = tmp; } else { ptr->next = tmp; ptr = tmp; }`, you could factor out the creation/initialization of node from `if`/`else`. (This works based on the assumption that `start` _and_ `ptr` are initially `NULL`.)

Comment: @Scheff `if (start==NULL)` is not _necessary_.  `if (start==NULL) ...else ..` is just one way of many to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to do it Without using the if(start==NULL) ...else .. statement?

Yes

Create a head node and use only its `.next` member.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct node {
  int data;
  struct node* next;
};

int main(void) {
  struct node head = {.next = NULL};  // only need .next 
  struct node *ptr = &head;

  while (1) {
    // ...

    int n;
    printf("Enter the input ");
    fflush(stdout);
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
      break;
    }
    ptr->next = malloc(sizeof *ptr->next);
    if (ptr->next == NULL) {
      break;
    }
    ptr = ptr->next;
    ptr->data = n;
    ptr->next = NULL;
  }

  printf("\nThe output of the linked list is\n");
  ptr = head.next; // The start of the list is here
  while (ptr) {
    printf("  1 ptr =           %d\n", ptr->data);
    ptr = ptr->next;
  }
}
```

Comment: Touché. Without (ab)using a dummy node as list head, it's necessary to distinguish the case where `start` is `NULL`... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The `start` variable holds the **head** of the linked list.

The condition `if (start == NULL)` checks for an empty list.

If the list is empty, you need to create the head of the list. The second element onwards, you need to link the next element to the last element of the list. This is taken care by the `else` condition.

To look at it another way, if you do not have the `if` condition, you have the line

```
 ptr->next = tmp;
```

Since `ptr` is not initialized at this time, you will have undefined behaviour and most likely get a segmentation fault.

Answer (score -1):

Well, a lot of things are not necessary.

You can simply define a node as

```
struct node 
{
    int data;
    node * next; // Will hold the value of next node's address
};
```

Now you can simply make a Class of the data structure with methods.

```
class LinkedList {
  private:
    node *head, *current, *temp; // 3 Main pointers
  public:

    LinkedList() {
      head = temp = current = NULL; // Set them to NULL
    }

    void insert(int data) { // to add a new node
      if(head == NULL) { // if there is no node in the memory
        head = new node; // use head to make a new node
        head->data = data; // set the data of the node to data
        head->next = NULL; // set the next to NULL
        temp = current = head; // 3 pointers sitting at the head node
      }
      else { // If the node is not the first one in the memory
        current = new node; // use current pointer to make new node
        temp->next = current; // temp pointer one step behind the current node
        current->next = NULL; // make the next of new node NULL
        temp = current; // move the pointer to current
        current->data = data;
      }
    }
};
```

This function will simply add nodes on every call.

To display the list,
Simply move the temp pointer to head and start the iteration

```
void display()
{
    temp = head; // move to head
    while(temp != NULL) // while temp doesn't reach the end
    {
        cout<<temp->data<< " "; // print the node's data
        temp = temp->next; // move the pointer to next node
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments start with `//`, not with `\\\`

Comment: ...beside of the fact that this question is tagged [tag:c]. `class LinkedList`, `head = new node;`, etc. will probably give a syntax error in a C compiler.

Comment: This is C++ and not C

Comment: @Scheff Just about everything will generate a compiler error in a C compiler. :)

Comment: The logic is the main concern over here. He can use python for all I care.

Comment: That's why they introduced tags: [tag:c] for C related questions, [tag:c++] for C++ related questions, [tag:python] for Python related questions, and [tag:algorithm] for language agnostic questions about an algorithm in general. Btw. how comes that you mention Python? OP tagged [tag:c] and exposed code in C.

Comment: @IbtihajTahir Maybe so, but in that case you could at least avoid C++ specific constructs like classes. If you don't want to use the tagged language, use pseudo code. This would be a nightmare to translate to C for a beginner.